# In devexpress winforms, how can I import data into spreadsheet from a datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

Below is my code. Basically I just want to output data into my spreadsheet from a datatable, with its original columns and rows.

```
public Spreadsheet()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Worksheet worksheet = spreadsheetControl1.Document.Worksheets[0];

        string connectionString = null;
        SqlConnection conn;
        connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=jms";
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from students", connectionString);

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        DataTable dt5 = new DataTable("Students");

        worksheet.Import(dt5, true, 1, 1);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but you have not populated your `DataTable` with any data.

Your code should look like this:

```
DataTable dt5 = new DataTable("Students");

//this actually executes the SQL and populates the DataTable
sda.Fill(dt5);

worksheet.Import(dt5, true, 1, 1);
```